# reading from a text file in servlets

Tags: servlets, text-files

i have a login servlet from where i take a username and a password. i have a credentials.txt file where i have saved a few usernames followed by their passwords adjacently in a single line. once i read the username and password in my logincheck servlet, i want to search it in credentials.txt. if a match is found, we are directed to a welcomepage servlet, and if not found, we are again directed to the login servlet. i am getting array out of bounds exception in my code.

Plz help correct my code.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String user=request.getParameter("username");
    String pass=request.getParameter("password");
    File obj=new File("credentials.txt");
    FileReader reader=new FileReader(obj);
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(reader);      
    String aks[],temp1,temp2;
    int i=0;
    String line=in.readLine();
    while(line!=null){
        aks=line.split("\t");
        while(aks[i+1]!=null){
        temp1=aks[i];
        temp2=aks[i+1];
        if(temp1.equals(user) && temp2.equals(pass)){
            RequestDispatcher obj1=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomepage");
            obj1.forward(request,response);
        }
        line=in.readLine();
    }
    }
    String errormsg="username and password do not match. Please re-enter";
    request.setAttribute("errormsg",errormsg);
    RequestDispatcher obj1=request.getRequestDispatcher("login");
    obj1.forward(request,response);

}
```

Comment: array index out of bounds exception to be precise.

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? All Servlet containers support FORM authentication and most (all?) support a simple file based list of users and passwords.

Comment: if this code is somewhat not useful or more complex than it should be....then how shud i verify the usernames and passwords saved in a simple text file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're thinking that `aks[i+1]!=null` will evaluate to false if the element `aks[i+1]` doesn't exist.  But if the element doesn't exist, it won't evaluate to anything; you'll always the exception you mentioned (index out of bounds).  Seems like maybe what you're looking to do is actually `while (aks.length>1)`.

Comment: applying ur solution worked. i am not getting any errors relating to arrays. but now my application isnt working. as soon as i click the login link after submitting my username and password, the page just keeps on processing but never goes to the next page. it isnt showing any errors though.